# Parameters properties Menu Item Button in AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I see  "parameters" in properties of Menu Item Button. How can I send a parameter by this property and get it in form in x++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `parameters` you can specify the arguments that will be passed to the object. Then you can get it in form:

```
str  parm;
;

parm = element.args().parm();
```

Comment: In properties can I write for example myParam=10?

Comment: You can pass any string.